# Too much poop in tags

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

At the moment, Medical Sciences SE has tag [stools-fecal-matter-poop](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stools-fecal-matter-poop) and tag [defecate-poop](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/defecate-poop).

1. In order not to have [synonyms in tag names](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1203/12704), how about having tag [stools](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stools) with synonyms [faecal-matter](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faecal-matter), [fecal-matter](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fecal-matter) and [poop](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poop)?
2. Since there is already a tag for poop, how about tag [defecation](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/defecation) instead of tag [defecate-poop](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/defecate-poop)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implemented mostly as suggested but did not create [poop](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poop). I don't think it's needed and making one would mean it's both a noun (as a synonym for [stools](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stools)) and a verb (as a synonym for [defecation](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/defecation).

Also note that the synonyms needs to be upvoted.

Comment: Might be worth pinging a fellow mod to approve the synonyms, I don't know how that works exactly but it seems you need enough tag rep for someone else to upvote them, which is going to be difficult to find an active user for many of these tags

Comment: @BryanKrause Yeah, I'm going to look into how that works. I also noticed that people have to have rep associated with the tag and some of these are pretty obscure.

Comment: Hmm, this old meta post: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145302/force-tag-synonym-if-a-mod-tries-to-make-one-even-if-its-already-suggested seems to suggest mods can both suggest and also outright create...but if you "suggest" first then you're screwed. Not sure if that's up-to-date...

Comment: Maybe try from here: https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms

Comment: @BryanKrause Bingo! That page allowed me to approve them. The fact that they won't let me approve it when I create it is, I think, a bit of a bug.